# Why am I getting the error "invalid type closure"?

Tags: r, closures

```
W <- ecdf(c(1,2,3))
W
O <- sum(W)
W
```

Why does this not work? I get

```
Error in sum(W) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
```

Didn't quite understand the answer to the other similar posts since I'm quite new to this. How do I fix it?

Comment: Just like the error message is telling you: The `W` object is a function (with an attached environment that holds the values you passed to it). If you provide an R function some values it will return values. That's how R works. You don't say what you were expecting so further comments would be speculative.

Comment: w is a function then? How do I store values from the function w, to compute the sum of its elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ecdf` function is really a functional, i.e. its value is another function. In R the things we call "functions" are really "closures". They have a body that is the code block that is easy to see by typing the function name. However they also have an *environment* that carries around the local values of variables that are defined at the time of the closure's creation.

If you don't want to provide new values to W that is different than the original values used for its creation, then you need to extract the values from the environment holding the values that existed (and were created) at the time of the call to `ecdf` with .... wait for it .... the `environment`-function. The `ls` function will return the names of the contents of that environment:

```
 str(W)
#--------
function (v)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ecdf" "stepfun" "function"
 - attr(*, "call")= language ecdf(1:11)
#---------------
 # Just asking to see that environment is less than satisfying
  environment(W)
 #<environment: 0x3cd392588>
 # using `ls` is more informative
 ls( environment(W) )
#[1] "f"      "method" "nobs"   "x"      "y"      "yleft"  "yright"
```

To deliver the sum of the original x-values:

```
> sum( environment(W)$x )
[1] 6
```

It is possible to display the entire contents of an environment by coercing to a data-object with `as.list`:

```
> as.list(environment(W))
$nobs
[1] 3

$x
[1] 1 3 5

$y
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000

$method
[1] 2

$yleft
[1] 0

$yright
[1] 1

$f
[1] 0
```